# Merging one field on two different fields

Tags: sql, excel

In my database I have one table with multiple fields and two of them: a and b are just numbers that do not give any information.
In another table, I have the definition of these two fields but the definitions are in the same table and same field. Here is how the second table is constructed:

- TNAME: what the code is used for (a or b)
- TCODE: numbers used in the first table
- HEADING: defintion of the numbers

I'm trying to merge fied "a" on TCODE where TNAME is "a" and to merge field "b" on TCODE where TNAME is "b".
I tried to create two temporary table so I could work on new fields with different names but once the table is cretated I cannot drop it (I tried different wyas but nothing work).

Does anyone know how I could solve this problem?
I'm working in MS Excel with my databases.

Thanks!

Comment: And the question is? how to drop the table?

Comment: If it works with dropping the table that would be great unless there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Your description is unclear. Please clarify & give example before and after data. Please explain what "tried" and "ways" mean here.